# How can we change background color of Badge notifications for Windows apps in uwp

Tags: uwp, badge

I'm trying to show Numeric badges over the taskbar icon in my uwp application using following method

```
 XmlDocument badgeXml = 
    BadgeUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(BadgeTemplateType.BadgeNumber);

// Set the value of the badge in the XML to our number
XmlElement badgeElement = badgeXml.SelectSingleNode("/badge") as XmlElement;
badgeElement.SetAttribute("value", num.ToString());

// Create the badge notification
BadgeNotification badge = new BadgeNotification(badgeXml);

// Create the badge updater for the application
BadgeUpdater badgeUpdater = 
    BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication();

// And update the badge
badgeUpdater.Update(badge);
```

Is there any way to show count in the red circular background, the same way Microsoft teams app does?

[image: Badge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we change background color of Badge notifications for Windows apps in uwp

UWP app only allow update `BadgeNumber` or `BadgeGlyph`, and currently there is no way to change the  background color of Badge notifications. And above screenshot is desktop app that show the badge with [`TaskbarItemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo?view=netframework-4.8), But UWP does not support `TaskbarItemInfo` class, if you do want this feature, please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub.

Comment: Is this possible now? Also how can we do using TaskbarItemInfo? Can you have reference?